# heroku delayed_job stalling though process is running, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

im trying to get delayed_job to work in heroku. 
ive been following

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job and 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

i created a Procfile on my root and passed in

```
worker: rake jobs:work
```

my delayed_job works on my development machine when i do either

```
rake jobs:work
foreman start
```

however, on heroku it cant seem to find my delayed_jobs. when i run

```
heroku ps
```

it says

```
Process   State       Command
--------  ----------  ---------------------------------
run.1     up for 27m  bundle exec rails console
web.1     up for 28m  bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker.1  up for 28m  rake jobs:work
```

i did the command

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

earlier (i dont think i have to do it again...)

just to check if my jobs are running (which they should) i did

```
heroku console
irb(main):001:0> Delayed::Job.all
```

but this returns to me

```
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" => []
```

it doesn't seem to find the delayed_job.

in my code, i executed something like

```
$index.document(@lesson.id).delay.update_variables({ 0 => new_score})
```

and delayed_job works in my development.

i tried to isolate the problem then by just doing

```
heroku run bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

however all that it spits out is...

```
Running bundle exec rake jobs:work attached to terminal... up, run.2
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
[Worker(host:39da7fc7-7b64-49c1-8e8c-36242e705abf pid:7)] Starting job worker
```

why does it stall in production when i try running it?

thank you.

Comment: It's normal for that table to be empty - delayed jobs deletes jobs when they finish. By default it also deletes them if they fail - there's a config option that allows you to keep those so you can work out why they failed

Comment: Are you using any class/module from lib directory or something that is no in the autoload path? If so, the jobs would fail and be removed right away from the Delayed::Job table as Frederick mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried to open console on your heroku instance and manually add a delayed_job to see if the worker tries to perform it?